# How can I disable transactions for a Hive table?

Tags: hive, hiveddl

I have a Hive table that was originally created as transactional, but I want to disable transactions on the table because they are not actually needed.

I tried to disable them using `ALTER TABLE`, but I got an error:

```
hive> ALTER TABLE foo SET TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='false');
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. TBLPROPERTIES with 'transactional'='true' cannot be unset
```

I am using Hive 2.3.2

Comment: Make a new table, that's your only option as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-TableProperties) changing TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="false") is not allowed.

You can re-create the table.

Do table backup first:

```
create table bkp_table as 
select * from your_table;
```

Then drop table and create again without `transactional` property. Reload data from backup.

Or make a new table, load data from old one, delete old, rename new.

Comment: I don't think you can just copy the directory and drop a new hive table on top of it.  Hive acid tables will have base and delta files, don't know how a non-acid table would be able to read those.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you very much for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-create the table.

First backup table if you want. then, `DROP TABLE`

Create Table with `TBLPROPERTIES ( 'transactional'='false' )`

```
CREATE TABLE your_table(
  `col` string, 
  `col2` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
  'transactional'='false' 
)
```

You can Choose Input and Output format